# Ionic native device plugin @ionic-native/device returns all nulls

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-plugins

I need to do a device detection in my Ionic project so I've installed `@ionic-native/device` plugin per instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/

However when I wire it in inside of a component, then run `ionic serve` to preview changes, console.log returns `Device` object with all values set to `null`, same happens when I try to use individual property e.g. `this.device.model`:
[image: console.log output]

Here is how I use it inside of a component:

```
import {Device} from "@ionic-native/device";
// ...

@Component({
    // ...
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private device: Device) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.device);
    }

}
```

And I've added it to `AppModule` as well:

```
import {Device} from "@ionic-native/device";
// ...

@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        Device
    ]
})
export class AppModule() {
}
```

Cordova device plugin was auto injected into `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget <!-- ... --> >
    <!-- ... -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Here is my Ionic stack (at least packages that should be relevant to the issue):

```
"@angular/*": "^5.2.4",      // all packages
"@ionic-native/*": "4.5.2",  // all packages

"@ionic-native/device": "4.5.2"
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.0",
"typescript": "2.6.2"
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get device details in the browser by running:

```
cordova run browser
```

This assumes you have added browser as a platform, if not run:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

(From the link in the answer posted by @AndrewLively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034015/448816)

Comment: What platform are you testing/developing against?

Comment: @AndrewLively I'm building against iOS and Android, but I'm trying to see device info in the browser (Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running in the browser using `ionic serve` then most of the ionic-native plugins won't work since it is not treated by ionic as a valid browser platform.

This is not well documented, but is discussed in an [issue in the ionic-native repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1752#issuecomment-312531041).

Comment: I able to get it working by running `cordova run browser` as mentioned in the ionic issue response you posted (I had already added `browser` as a app platform), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should see the packages installed and see they are in the same version in "package.json"

[image]

Core and Native packages must be in the same version or the native package should not be larger.

[image]

The folder "platforms" must be delete

[image]

Use these commands

```
    ionic build

    ionic cordova platform add browser

    cordova run browser
```

code for .ts

```
console.log('Device Model is: ' + this.device.model);
```

And works !

[image]